# Jenkins Reverse Proxy Nginx

Tags: nginx, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I set up Jenkins on my Ubuntu 18.04 server.

I want to access it via https://domain.tld/jenkins.

Everything works as expected except, in Jenkins setting, it shows me "It appears that your Reverse Proxy Server is broken."

I already checked the Jenkins URL in the settings, it is set to https://domain.tld/jenkins

This is my nginx config file:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name  domain.tld;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location /jenkins/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/;

                proxy_redirect http:// https://;

                proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_read_timeout 90;

                proxy_redirect http:// https://;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
                proxy_buffering on;
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `--prefix=/jenkins` to the `JENKINS_ARGS` in the configuration file? See the **Running Jenkins from a folder with TLS encryption** in [This Guide](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS//Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy)